# AngularJS: Cannot reach variable in the controller after ui-router resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, components

I have following code in config. I use `ui-router`

```
template: "<employee-info-component user='$resolve.user'></employee-info-component>",
      resolve: {
           user: function () {
                return 'hello!';
           }
      }
```

binding in component:

```
binding:{
    user: '<'
}
```

I can not reach `$ctrl.user` in controller of `employee-info-component`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: the key of resolve will be injected in the controller of the route instead of instead of direct access in template, because it may be promise as well which is not resolved before template render
cehck here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: Thanks for answer! But what do you mean by before `template render cehck here`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `binding` property in component. There is only `bindings` property, where we can specify variables, that will be linked. So you just made mistake in syntax

Answer (score 0):

user should be used as a dependency in the controller and not in template. If you want, inject user to the controller and bind it to a scope variable and then use it.